# Problems with iframe in mobile. Duplicate content when you scroll

Tags: android, jquery, mobile, iframe, cordova

I'm developing a mobile application that is basically an iframe. The fact is that sometimes the content is duplicated when browsing in iframe (click on links, back button ...) and I scroll down. Both the app and the android default browser same thing happens, so I rule out problems on the app (phonegap). I have not seen this error in any desktop browser (chrome, mozilla, ie).
Can anyone help me?. Thank you.